# Android Webview evaluateJavascript not able to find function inside a ES6 module file

Tags: javascript, android, ecmascript-6, android-webview

I have an Android `Webview` and I have an HTML file that is loaded inside the `WebView`.

The html has a function like this

```
<script>
function dummy() {
   console.log("inside dummy class");
}
</script>
```

Now when I call the below code, this works fine.

```
webView.evaluateJavascript('dummy()', null)
```

However when the script is an ES module like this, the above code is not able to find the function.

```
<script type="module">
function dummy() {
   console.log("inside dummy class");
}
</script>
```

The above example is a much simpler representation of the actual code. But I need to call `evaluateJavascript` from Android's Webview for functions which are present in a ES6 module file.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: did you find any solution?