# Android WebView can't find JS function when type="module"

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, three.js

I am experimenting displaying some 3D scenes through a WebView in Android using ThreeJS, and it is working fine except when it comes to interacting with the web layer and calling functions defined in it.

I need to call a JS function from within Android code when a pager is scrolled. I am achieving this with:

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = pagerState) {
        snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
             println("Android: Page selected $page")
             webView?.evaluateJavascript("onPageSelected($page);", null)
             //webView?.loadUrl("javascript:onPageSelected($page);")
       }
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't work, I get this error:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: onPageSelected is not defined", source: http://192.168.0.15:5173/ (1)
```

I tried both `evaluateJavascript` and the commented-out `loadUrl` and none of them work.

This is how my WebView is setup. I think everything is OK because the 3D is rendering as expected

```
AndroidView(
      factory = { context ->
                WebView(context).apply {
                   settings.apply {
                       javaScriptEnabled = true
                       javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
                       domStorageEnabled = true
                   }
                webViewClient = CustomWebViewClient().apply {}
                loadUrl("http://192.168.0.15:5173/")
            }
     },
     update = { webView = it },
     modifier = modifier
)
```

And this is the HTML + JS code being displayed in the WebView:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>three.js webgl - lights - point lights</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"
          name="viewport">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "../build/three.module.js",
                    "three/addons/": "./jsm/"
                }
            }

</script>
<script type="module">

            import * as THREE from 'three';

            import Stats from 'three/addons/libs/stats.module.js';

            import { OBJLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/OBJLoader.js';

            let camera, scene, renderer,
                light1, light2, light3, light4,
                object, stats;

            const clock = new THREE.Clock();

            init();
            animate();
            onPageSelected(0);

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.z = 100;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                //model

                const loader = new OBJLoader();
                //const objPath = 'models/obj/walt/WaltHead.obj'
                const objPath = 'models/obj/male02/male02.obj'
                loader.load(objPath, function ( obj ) {

                    object = obj;
                    object.scale.multiplyScalar( 0.8 );
                    object.position.y = - 30;
                    scene.add( object );

                } );

                const sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.5, 16, 8 );

                //lights

                light1 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xff0040, 400 );
                light1.add( new THREE.Mesh( sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0040 } ) ) );
                scene.add( light1 );

                light2 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x0040ff, 400 );
                light2.add( new THREE.Mesh( sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0040ff } ) ) );
                scene.add( light2 );

                light3 = new THREE.PointLight( 0x80ff80, 400 );
                light3.add( new THREE.Mesh( sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x80ff80 } ) ) );
                scene.add( light3 );

                light4 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffaa00, 400 );
                light4.add( new THREE.Mesh( sphere, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffaa00 } ) ) );
                scene.add( light4 );

                //renderer

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                //stats

                stats = new Stats();
                document.body.appendChild( stats.dom );

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();
                stats.update();

            }

            function render() {

                const time = Date.now() * 0.0005;
                const delta = clock.getDelta();

                if ( object ) object.rotation.y -= 0.5 * delta;

                light1.position.x = Math.sin( time * 0.7 ) * 30;
                light1.position.y = Math.cos( time * 0.5 ) * 40;
                light1.position.z = Math.cos( time * 0.3 ) * 30;

                light2.position.x = Math.cos( time * 0.3 ) * 30;
                light2.position.y = Math.sin( time * 0.5 ) * 40;
                light2.position.z = Math.sin( time * 0.7 ) * 30;

                light3.position.x = Math.sin( time * 0.7 ) * 30;
                light3.position.y = Math.cos( time * 0.3 ) * 40;
                light3.position.z = Math.sin( time * 0.5 ) * 30;

                light4.position.x = Math.sin( time * 0.3 ) * 30;
                light4.position.y = Math.cos( time * 0.7 ) * 40;
                light4.position.z = Math.sin( time * 0.5 ) * 30;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

            function onPageSelected(page) {
                console.log("hello world " + page);
            }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Interesting observation:
The `onPageSelected(0);` called from within the JS code itself works as expected and I get this logged:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(122)] "hello world 0", source: http://192.168.0.15:5173/index.html?html-proxy&index=0.js (122)
```

It's curious that the "source" is different than the function call that failed.

Another interesting thing is that if I move the function definition out of this
`<script type="module">` block, into it's own `<script>` block, it works! But I need it to be in that block because I need it to alter a variable that is used during 3D rendering.

So my assumption is that this  `type="module"` thing is changing the visibility of the function and preventing it from being accessible from Android. I found a similar unanswered question from years ago with the same problem: [Android Webview evaluateJavascript not able to find function inside a ES6 module file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64771814/android-webview-evaluatejavascript-not-able-to-find-function-inside-a-es6-module)
I wonder what can be done to fix it?

Comment: When you use modules, the global symbols in the module are **not** exposed as properties of the real global object (`window`). Your code has to do that explicitly.

Comment: @Pointy and how can I do that? I have very limited knowledge of JS! would appreciate any help!

Comment: `window.functionName = functionName;` though it would be better to use programmatic event handler management (`.addEventListener()` etc).